# Custom dataset Loader pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

**i am doing  covid-19 classification.i took dataset from kaggle. it has folder named dataset which contain 3 folders normal pnuemonia and covid-19 each contaning images for these classes i am stucked in writting **getitem** in pytorch custom dataloader ?**
Dataset has 189 covid images but by this get item i get 920 images of covid kindly help

```
class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
root_dir = 'COVID-19 Radiography Database'
source_dirs = ['NORMAL', 'Viral Pneumonia', 'COVID-19']

 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_dir, source_dirs[1])):
   os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test'))

for i, d in enumerate(source_dirs):
    os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, d), os.path.join(root_dir, class_names[i]))

for c in class_names:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'test', c))

for c in class_names:
    images = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, c)) if x.lower().endswith('png')]
    selected_images = random.sample(images, 30)
    for image in selected_images:
        source_path = os.path.join(root_dir, c, image)
        target_path = os.path.join(root_dir, 'test', c, image)
        shutil.move(source_path, target_path)
```

**Above code is used to create test dataset which has 30 images of each class**

```
 class ChestXRayDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
   def __init__(self, image_dirs, transform):
      def get_images(class_name):
        images = [x for x in os.listdir(image_dirs[class_name]) if 
        x[-3:].lower().endswith('png')]
        print(f'Found {len(images)} {class_name} examples')
        return images
    
    self.images = {}
    self.class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
    
    for class_name in self.class_names:
        self.images[class_name] = get_images(class_name)
        
    self.image_dirs = image_dirs
    self.transform = transform
    

def __len__(self):
    return sum([len(self.images[class_name]) for class_name in self.class_names])


def __getitem__(self, index):
    class_name = random.choice(self.class_names)
    index = index % len(self.images[class_name])
    image_name = self.images[class_name][index]
    image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dirs[class_name], image_name)
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
    return self.transform(image), self.class_names.index(class_name)
```

**Stucked in get item of this **

[images in folder are arranged as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqToR.png)
[Dataset is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zwUz.png)

**Code for confusion matrix is **

```
nb_classes = 3

 confusion_matrix = torch.zeros(nb_classes, nb_classes)
 with torch.no_grad():
 for data in tqdm_notebook(dl_train,total=len(dl_train),unit='batch'):
    img,lab = data
    print(lab)
    img,lab = img.to(device),lab.to(device)
    _,output = torch.max(model(img),1)
    print(output)
    
    for t, p in zip(lab.view(-1), output.view(-1)):
            confusion_matrix[t.long(), p.long()] += 1
```

**output for confusion matrix only one class is getting trained**
[confusio matrix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylfog.png)

Comment: `only one class is getting trained` - most likely because your model is too weak to do anything more useful than predicting the most common class all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Putting you images in a dictionary complicates the manipulation, rather use a list. Also you Dataset should not have any randomness, shuffling of the data should happen from the DataLoader not from the Dataset.

Use something like below:

```
 class ChestXRayDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
   def __init__(self, image_dirs, transform):
      def get_images(class_name):
        images = [x for x in os.listdir(image_dirs[class_name]) if 
        x[-3:].lower().endswith('png')]
        print(f'Found {len(images)} {class_name} examples')
        return images
    
    self.images = []
    self.labels = []
    self.class_names = ['normal', 'viral', 'covid']
    
    for class_name in self.class_names:
        images = get_images(class_name)
        # This is a list containing all the images
        self.images.extend(images)
        # This is a list containing all the corresponding image labels
        self.labels.extend([class_name]*len(images))
        
    self.image_dirs = image_dirs
    self.transform = transform
    

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.images)

# Will return the image and its label at the position `index`
def __getitem__(self, index):
    # image at index position of all the images
    image_name = self.images[index]
    # Its label 
    class_name = self.labels[index]
    image_path = os.path.join(self.image_dirs[class_name], image_name)
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
    return self.transform(image), self.class_names.index(class_name)
```

If you enumerate it say using

```
ds = ChestXRayDataset(image_dirs, transform)
for x, y in ds:
   print (x.shape, y)
```

You should see all the images and the labels in the sequential order.

However in real case you would rather use a Torch DataLoader and pass it the `ds` object with shuffle parameter set to `True`. So the DataLoader will take care of shuffling the Dataset by calling the `__getitem__` with shuffled `index` values.

Comment: can you explain me little bit more of what we are doing ? Sorry for disturbing you

Comment: @MuditGupta updated the answer with comments

Comment: i used that but its not working fine should i add link to colab notebook so that you can suggest me changes

Comment: i worked fine there but after training confusion matrix printed is liketensor([[1311.,    0.,    0.],
        [1315.,    0.,    0.],
        [ 189.,    0.,    0.]]) why is it so

Comment: Because you have three classes your confusion matrix will be of size `3 X 3` as expected

Comment: but only one class is identified by model